# don't understand "does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'”"

Tags: c#, class

I don't understand how I fix this issue. I have two `foreach` loops:

```
foreach (deviceDetailsModel.Detail d in ddm.device.details)
{
    foreach (deviceDetailsModel.Entry e in d)
    {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

on the 2nd for loop I get the `does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'` error. What am I doing wrong?

This is the class:

```
public class deviceDetailsModel
{
    public int totalCount { get; set; }
    public string messages { get; set; }
    public Device device { get; set; }

    public class Entry
    {
        public string key { get; set; }
        public object value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Detail
    {
        public List<Entry> entry { get; set; }
    }

    public class Device
    {
        public string @id { get; set; }
        public string uuid { get; set; }
        public string principal { get; set; }
        public int blockReason { get; set; }
        public int clientId { get; set; }
        public string comment { get; set; }
        public int compliance { get; set; }
        public int countryCode { get; set; }
        public int countryId { get; set; }
        public string countryName { get; set; }
        public string createdAt { get; set; }
        public string currentPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public List<Detail> details { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you meant:

```
deviceDetailsModel.Entry e in d.entry
```

instead.

You're getting the error because `d` (presumably an instance of the `Detail` class) doesn't implement `IEnumerable`. You probably wanted to enumerate over the `entry` property instead.